# Why isn't SBT copying generated resources to the classes folder?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I have written a plugin to process some SQL files and generate new ones as managed resources. When I run 'sbt compile' the files are generated in to the target/resource_managed/main/sql folder. When I run 'sbt run' or 'sbt test' they are not copied into the target/classes directory like I expect, so the code that is looking for them on the classpath cannot find them.

Here is the code for the plugin:

```
object SqlProcessorPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  import autoImport._

  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = noTrigger

  object autoImport {
    lazy val processorSettings = taskKey[File]("Settings for sql processing")
    lazy val processSqlTask = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Process Sql")

    def configProcessor(cfg: Configuration) = {
      inConfig(cfg) {
        Seq(
          target in processorSettings := resourceManaged.value / "sql",
          sourceDirectory in processorSettings := sourceDirectory.value / "sql",
          processSqlTask / fileInputs += (sourceDirectory in processorSettings).value.toGlob / ** / "*.sql",
          processSqlTask := {
            SqlProcessor.process(
              processSqlTask.inputFileChanges,
              (target in processorSettings).value
            )
          },
          resourceGenerators += processSqlTask.taskValue,
        )
      }
    }

    override val projectSettings = configProcessor(Compile)
  }
}
```

I've try lots of variations on this based upon examples from other questions and from other plugins, but nothing has resulted in the generated files being copied to the class path.

What an I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: Does `SqlProcessor.process` return all generated files?

Comment: Yes, it returns the files that are generated. I figured out that it is copying the files, just not where I expected. Instead of target/classes, it's copying them to target/classes/scala-2.13/classes/resource_managed. How do I get them to be copied directly under the classes folder?

Answer (score 0):

I figured ou the issue. I was using resourceManage.value instead of (Compile/resourceManaged).value as the target directory. Also, I think as a result it was messing up the relative path on the output files resulting in them being copied to the wrong place.